# Find the value of $\cos\left({\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}\right)$.

Tags: trigonometry

Find the value of $$\cos\left({\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)}\right)$$

Comment: Try to relate it to a 3-4-5 triangle.

Comment: I didn't understand

Comment: Draw a right triangle that contains an angle with tangent $\frac 34$.

Comment: What, precisely, didn't you understand? Do you know what a triangle is?

Comment: Will you please solve this question using inverse trigonometric functions?

Comment: use the formula: $\cos^2 \alpha = \frac1{1+\tan^2 \alpha}$.

Comment: Wrong tags here. This should be tagged "trigonometry".

Comment: @user187387 What's wrong with drawing a triangle out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From $\sin^2(x)+ \cos^2(x)=1$ if you devide by $\cos^2$ and rearrange, you get
$$
\cos^2(x)=\frac{1}{\tan^2 (x)+1}
$$
then set $x=\tan^{-1}(y)$, taking the square root yelds
$$
\cos(\tan^{-1}(y))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}
$$
In case $y=3/4$, so $\cos(\tan^{-1}(3/4))=4/5$

Comment: Nice answer! In your first line, a better place to start from might be $\tan^2 x + 1 = \sec^2 x$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this right angled triangle [image]

From the figure $$tan \theta=\dfrac{3}{4}$$

$$\implies \theta=\tan ^{-1} \dfrac{3}{4}$$

So

$$\cos (\tan ^{-1} \dfrac{3}{4})=\cos \theta$$

From the triangle,

$$\cos \theta=\dfrac{4}{5}$$